# Tell Watir to use a specific FireFox app on Mac

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using Ruby Watir. When it opens a browser, it opens FireFox. However, I think it is not the same FireFox I use, because it doesn't have any of the plugins I normally have.

Is it possible to tell Watir to use *my* FireFox app? (I am using Mac OSX Yosemite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely using the same Firefox browser, just that it's creating a new Firefox profile (different profiles do not share extensions in Firefox)

From [the documentation](http://watirwebdriver.com/firefox/):

> By default, the Firefox driver creates a new Firefox profile for each test run, which is the recommended action.
>
> You can specify an existing profile to use, such as your ‘default’ profile:

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => 'default'
```